# I want to set my date picker to only allow even hour choices

Tags: ios, swift, date, datepicker

For example only allow 6:00pm, 7:00pm but not 6:30 pm or 10:20pm.

I have looked into using the date picker property `picker.minuteInterval` but that restricts you to certain increments, but does not allow you do even hours.

Any advice or information regarding the matter is much appreciated.

Comment: You will either need to post-process the selected value and round it up or down to the nearest hour or use your own `UIPickerView`

Comment: can you share your code or screenshot?

Comment: please post your code that you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
datepicker.minuteInterval = 30 //this is max
datepicker.date = Date().nearestEvenHourDate //initial date

 @IBAction func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    datepicker.date = datepicker.date.nearestEvenHourDate //selected date manipuated
 }

extension Date {
    var nearestEvenHourDate: Date {
        var hours = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: self).hour ?? 0
        hours = hours % 2 == 0 ? hours : hours - 1
        return Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: hours, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)!
    }
}
```

Play around with nearestEvenHourDate to get the desired behaviour (handle minutes to increase the hours perhaps)